# When to use in or at the flat?

Tags: prepositions

When do you use *in* and when *at* the flat, in English?
Can I say both

> I live in the flat.
>
> I live at the flat.

Here's what prompted this question; a passage from a textbook goes like this: A girl arrived in a city where she was going to live for a while, in a new flat. Her friend picked her up at the airport.

She: ´How is your wife?´
He: ´She is fine, she is at your new flat.´

Which means, if somebody stays in a flat which is not his/hers, then he/she is AT someone´s flat, not IN someone´s flat?

Comment: Are you talking about one flat in particular?

Answer (score 5):

If you are discussing the flat and its possible uses, then you'd say

> I live in the flat.

or

> I rent out the flat.

If you are discussing types of residence, then you'd say

> I live in a flat.

or

> I live in a house.

If you are discussing possible general locations, maybe the others know you own a flat and a house, then you'd say

> I live at the flat.

or

> I live at the house.

or

> I live at the seaside.

If you are talking about a larger area then use 'in', so

> I live in Paris.

If you live in the Netherlands, then you'd say

> I live in the Netherlands.

Comment: Regarding your example *I rent out the flat*. The common terminology for this in the UK, is *let* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/let_3 It can also be *I let the flat*.

Answer (score 4):

You always live *in* a dwelling and never *at*. Something like I live in a small house.

For others, an apartment is often called a flat in India. I guess the OP is talking in Indian dialect.

> I live in a flat - is correct.

On the other hand you always *stay* at someone's house. There using *in* may not be preferred.

> I'm staying *at* my aunt's house.

Comment: Maulik V, not just in India. The word *flat* is often used in the UK, as well.

Comment: Yeah. And India uses British English. However the op seems to be Indian and here on this site I'm always asked to clarify every word I say. Or else the whole thing heads some other way ;)

Comment: The word _flat_ refers to an apt in the U.S. as well.

Comment: I guess the moral of the story is you don't need to drag India into every thing, just because you are from India. :P